# Input fields are longer than grid in IE and Mozilla

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I cannot find a class collidating with my Contact form. The form is in bootstrap but its fields extend the grid in Mozilla and IE.

What is the issue?

```
    <section>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">

            </div>      
            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">            
                    <h2>formularz kontaktowy</h2>
                        <?php echo do_shortcode ('[contact-form-7 id="81" title="Kontakt"]'); ?>
            </div>      
        </div>
    </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: try: box-sizing: border-box;   http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp .  Also for your text area remove the cols.

Comment: Please post your code within the question. Otherwise if and when you fix this problem your question here will be useless to future visitors.

Comment: it's already in the code
        * {
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

Comment: its because of `size="40"` you mentioned. Reduced it.

Comment: Unfortunately `size="40"` is generated automatically, it's also in my other projects and works fine there.

Comment: what if you use `width` for `input` field. like this `input.wpcf7-text[type="text"]{width:40%;}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SIZE="S":` defines the number of characters “S” that will appear in the text box.  More text can be typed, but it all just will not appear at once in the text box.

> Note:  In most cases, SIZE="40" should provide more than adequate
>   space for a text box.

So to fix your issue there is a work around. In your case you can give a `width` to the input field.

```
input.wpcf7-text[type="text"]{width:30%; color:red;}
```

Comment: thank you very much! even with `width:100%` works like a charm.